# Http get query parameters from different lists

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to make an HTTP GET request to retrieve some filtered data. 
My API accept 3 array of parameters and in my code I have 3 different lists of parameters.
Is it possible to create a Map that contains parameters with same key and different values from 3 lists of int?

```dart
Future<List<Tour>> fetchFilteredTours(List<int> bikeTypeIds,
      final List<int> difficultyIds, final List<int> locationIds) async {
    final Map<String, String> qryParams = {
    };

    //How to create my qryParams with all arrays values?
    //Something like
    qryParams.add(Map.fromIterable(bikeTypeIds, key: (e) => 'bikeTypeId', value: (e) => e));

    final response = await http
        .get(Uri.http('myDomain', '/api/search/tours', qryParams));

    return parseResponse(response);
  }
```

The desired result is `{{protocol}}://{{url}}/api/search/tours?bikeTypeId=1&bikeTypeId=2&difficultyId=1&locationId=1`

Comment: Use `String`, instead `Map`.

Comment: Yes I can use string. But mine is a `map` study case

Comment: What do you want qryParams ['bikeTypeId'] to return ?

Comment: The problem is not what I want to return, but what the `Uri.http()` accept. It accepts `Map<String,String>` but in a map you cannot put entries with same key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  final keys = ['bikeTypeId', 'difficultyId', 'locationId'];

  final values = [bikeTypeIds, difficultyIds, locationIds].map(
    (ids) => ids.map((e) => e.toString()),
  );
```

Create a Map instance associating the given keys to values.

```
  final qryParams = Map.fromIterables(keys, values);
```

Create a new URI from its components.

```
  Uri(scheme: 'https', host: 'myDomain', path: 'api/search/tours', queryParameters: qryParams);
```

Comment: `Uri(host: 'myDomain', path: 'api/search/tours', queryParameters: qryParams);` does not supports http/s domains. In my resquest I specified `Uri.http()` because mine is an HTTP GET request. My domain will be something like `http://www.example.com`

Answer (score 0):

Try `qryParams.add(Map.fromIterable(bikeTypeIds, key: (e) => 'bikeTypeId', value: (e) => '$e'))`

Which would provide the `Map<String, String>` that `Uri.http` requires.  In your code you are trying to create a `Map<String, int>` ... Notice the `'$e'`

Comment: Hey brian, thanks for the `'$e'`. It was a stupid error. The main problem is that  `map.add()` method does not exist